# Deterministically Generating cryptographically secure keys and IVEC's

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, secret-key, crypto++

**Background**

I am designing a system which enables the development of dynamic authentication schemes for a user of static web content. The motivation is to pre-generate large amounts of complex-to-generate, yet sensitive web-content, and then serve it statically with cookie-based (embedding reversably encrypted information) authentication in place, enforced by the web-server inately. Using an AEAD-mode encryption primitive.

**The Problem**

I need to generate IVEC's and keys that are valid for a duration of time, say one week (the current-valid pair). and that past IVECs/Keys are also valid for say 2 weeks(historically-valid) and any data encrypted with the historically valid secrets will just be re-encrypted with the current-valid IVEC/KEY.

What I need is a deterministic CSPRNG that seeds of a random number and a passphrase and that can produce in an indexed fashion 64-bit or 128-bit blocks of numbers. If I use a weeks-since-"jan 1 1970" as one of the index element of my hypothetical CSPRNG I should be able to build a system that innately changes keys automatically as time goes by.

**Approach I am Considering**

Now I don't see such functionality in cryptopp, or I do now know the terminology well enough, and as cryptopp is the most advanced of the encryption libraries out there, I don't have confidence I will find another one. So, If I can't find an implementation out there, I should roll my own. Will generating a static string structure out of the concatinated data and then hashing it (shown below) do the trick ?

RIPEMD160(RandomPreGeneratedFixedNonce:PassPhrase:UInt64SinceEpoch:128BitBlockIndexNumber);

Note: The blocknumbers will be assigned and have a regular structure, so for example for a 128-bit digest, the first 64-bits of block 0 will be for the ivec, and all of element 1 for the 128-bit key.

Is this a sound approach (--.i.e, cryptographically secure) ?

**-- edit: post accept comment --**

After some reflection, I have decided to merge what I originally considered the passphrase and the nonce/salt into a 16-byte (cryptographicall strong) key, and use the techniques outlined in the PKCS #5 to derive multiple time-based keys. There isn't a need for a salt, as passphrases aren't used.

Comment: please tag with C++ if applicable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question.

First, your Initial Vectors don't have to be cryptographically strong random quantities, but they **should** be unique per-message. The IV is really just a kind of salt value that ensures that similar messages encrypted using the same key don't *look* similar once they're encrypted. You can use any quick pseudo-random generator to generate the IV, and then send it (preferably encrypted) along with the encrypted data.

The keys, of course, should be as strong as you can practically make them.

Your proposal to hash a text string containing a nonce, passphrase, and validity data seems to me to be very reasonable -- it's broadly in line with what is done by other system that use a passphrase to generate a key. You should hash more many times -- not just once -- to make the key generation computationally expensive (which will be a bigger problem for anyone trying to brute-force the key than it will for you).

You might also want to have a look at the key-generation scheme set out in PKCS#5 (e.g. at http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2898.html) which is implemented in cryptopp as PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction. This mechanism is already widely used and known to be reasonable secure (note that PKCS#5 recommends hashing the passphrase data at least 1000 times). You could just append your validity period and index data to the passphrase and use PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction as it stands.

You don't say what encryption algorithm you propose to use to encrypt the data, but I would suggest that you should pick something widely-used and known to be secure ... and in particular I'd suggest that you use AES. I'd also suggest using one of the SHA digest functions (maybe as an input to PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction). SHA-2 is current, but SHA-1 is sufficient for key generation purposes.

You also don't say what key length you're looking to generate, but you should be aware that the amount of entropy in your keys depends on the length of the passphrase that you use, and unless the passphrase is *very* long that will be much less than the keylength ideally requires.

The weakest link in this scheme is the passphrase itself, and that's always going to limit the level of security you can achive. As long as you salt your data (as you are doing) and make the key-generation expensive to slow down brute-force attacks you should be fine.

Comment: Very nicely written answer. The problem with sending the IV along with the message, is that it makes the message larger (in this case a cookie)/ However, I do not want to design a system where the IV is static forever. I designed a similar system before (research prototype) and I made sure the cookie generated began with the timestamp it was generated at, this made sure each message was unique, and also those cookies had 2 linearly increasing GUID's where at least one of them was unique per cookie. The GUID that changed came after the timestamp.  The system did however have a hard-coded IV.

Comment: The prototype of the system I am working on now, is currently first doing a authenticity pass (hmac-ripemd160), and then prepending the digest to the message and then running blowfish over the digest:message. I wasn't aware of AEAD-mode while I designed my system. I have to do more research in the area. I am hoping that one of the AEADs mode uses a digest by design.

Comment: **RFC** What are your thoughts on a hard-coded IV (or one that changes weekly) assuming the messages start with data that changes often ?

Comment: FWIW, I've been seeing reports of side-channel attacks on AES.  It's probably fine as long as you have control of the server, but if you let untrusted native processes run I'd consider using something else.

Comment: I've browsed through the first few page of the pcks5 standard (version 2.1) as per your recommendation. it's quite refreshing to see that my line of thinking is actually standardized best practise. I  hope the derivation classes in cryptopp support the psuedorandom function based approach outlined in the standard.

Comment: The purpose of the IV is to ensure that each message generates a unique ciphertext even when the same key is used for multiple messages. The reason for doing this is to avoid giving away any information about the plaintext through a trivial examination of the ciphertext (though it also makes various known-plaintext/known-ciphertext attacks harder). If you're confident that the plaintext messages differ sufficiently for these issues not to be a concern then you can get away without an IV, or with using a fixed known value. IVs of 0 are surprisingly common in real-world systems.

Comment: dajames, Hassan Syed: hard-coded IVs are useful if and only if you are changing key for every message. Please don't even think about reusing IV-key pair just because "messages are different enough". Here is simple and graphical explanation: http://www.cryptosmith.com/archives/70 Some cipher modes are not vulnerable to this attack, but it's better to play safe.

Comment: @blaze: I think you overstate the case. That's a nice example, but the illustration applies only to a one-time-pad, and the point it makes is only relevant to a poorly-designed cipher like WEP. The way that an IV affects the operation of a cipher depends on the chaining mode, but in *e.g.* CBC mode all the IV does is effectively prepend a known random cipher block to the start of the message to endure that each message **is** "different enough".

Comment: @dajames: one-time-pad is a keystream used only once, usually xored with data. Every good or bad stream cipher or block cipher in OFB mode (AES too :) essentially generating such keystream and hence should be only used once with each key-IV combination. Yes, CBC doesn't have such a problem, but should you rely on a comment "NEVER CHANGE CHAINING MODE HERE" in your code? It's better to have explicit message counter as part of IV or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is a deterministic CSPRNG that seeds of a random number and a passphrase and that can produce in an indexed fashion 64-bit or 128-bit blocks of numbers. If I use a weeks-since-"jan 1 1970" as one of the index element of my hypothetical CSPRNG I should be able to build a system that innately changes keys automatically as time goes by.

Well, I *think* part of the solution is to use a non-time based generator. That way, if both sides start with the same seed, then they both produce the same random stream. You can layer your "weeks since Week 1, 1970" logic on top of that.

To do that, you would use `OFB_mode<T>::Encryption`. It can be used as a generator because OFB mode uses `AdditiveCipherTemplate<T>`, which derives from `RandomNumberGenerator`.

In fact, Crpyto++ uses the generator in `test.cpp` so that results can be reproduced if something fails. Here's how you would use `OFB_mode<T>::Encryption`. It also applies to `CTR_Mode<T>::Encryption`:

```
SecByteBlock seed(32 + 16);
OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, seed, seed.size());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption prng;
    prng.SetKeyWithIV(seed, 32, seed + 32, 16);

    SecByteBlock t(16);
    prng.GenerateBlock(t, t.size());

    string s;
    HexEncoder hex(new StringSink(s));

    hex.Put(t, t.size());
    hex.MessageEnd();

    cout << "Random: " << s << endl;
}
```

The call to `OS_GenerateRandomBlock` fetches bytes from `/dev/{u|s}random` and then uses that as a simulated shared seed. Each run of the program will be different. Within each run of the program, it prints similar to the following:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
Random: DF3D3F8E8A21C39C0871B375013AA2CD
```

There's another generator available that does the same, but its not part of the Crypto++ library. Its called `AES_RNG`, and its based on AES-256. Its a header only implementation, and you can find it at the Crypto++ wiki under [RandomNumberGenerator](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator).

Also see the topic [Reproducibility](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#Reproducibility) for `RandomNumberGenerator` class on the Crypto++ wiki.